# Character output error

Tags: java

So I have my program working so it is able to move characters of a certain position to the right or left. However, once the text is moved it doesn't include spaces and is unable to handle unusual characters such as `^^''#` and just spits them out. Was hoping someone could give me a general idea/suggestion for why. Been trying to fix this for the past few hours but got nowhere.

```
public class hh {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line = "the spa^^^ce doesn't show***";
        char[] buffer = line.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
            char element = buffer[i];
            element = (char) (element + 5);
            if (element > 'z') {
                element = (char) (element - 26);
            } else if (element < 'a') {
                element = (char) (element + 26);
            }
            buffer[i] = element;
        }
        System.out.println(new String(buffer));
    }
}
```

Output:

> ymj?xufccchj?itjxsFy?xmtbIII

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following line you are increasing the char by 5, so all the spaces are converted to '%':

```
element = (char) (element + 5);
```

Since this value is smaller 'a' you increase it by 26 again:

```
element = (char) (element + 26);
```

This turns it into a question mark, see http://www.asciitable.com/

To prevent this you could add a condition, like:

```
if (element != ' ')
{
    // increase by 5, etc...
}
```

You might want to take a look at:

```
Character.isLetter(element);
```

Comment: this is where I apply my shift.. ..so I'm shifting each character by 5

Answer (score 1):

The space does't show because the ascii for space is 32.

You are adding 5 to it as `element = (char) (element + 5);`
so it becomes 32 + 5 = 37.

Now by this condition,

```
else if (element < 'a'){
     element = (char) (element + 26);
}
```

37 is less than the ascii of 'a' i.e. 97, so you are adding 26 to it which makes it 37 + 26 = 63 which is the ascii of ?(Question mark)